# Showing that a mapping of a topological space into a product space is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $(Y,T)$ and $(X_i,T_i)$, $i = 1,...,n$ be topological spaces.  Further for each $i$, let $f_i$ be a mapping of $(Y,T)$ into $(X_i, T_i)$.  Prove that the mapping $f: (Y,T) \rightarrow \prod (X_i,T_i)$, given by $f(y) = <f_1(y), f_2(y), ..., f_n(y)>$ is continuous iff each $f_i$ is continuous.

If $p_i$ is the projection mapping I know that $f_i = p_i \circ f$ is continuous because it is the composition of two continuous functions, but in the other direction I'm not sure if my answer is right.  I say:

Since $f_i = p_i \circ f$ then $p^{-1}_i \circ f_i = p^{-1}_i \circ (p_i \circ f) = f$, which is the composition of two continuous functions.  What I'm confused about is whether or not $p^{-1}_i \circ (p_i \circ f) =(p^{-1}_i \circ p_i) \circ f = f$.

Comment: $p_i^{-1}$ will fail to be a function in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open set in $\prod(X_i, T_i)$. We want to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

We know that the [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) is finer (i.e. has more open sets) than the product topology. This is because even in the box topology, every projection mapping $p_i$ is continuous, and because the product topology is defined to be the coarsest topology where this holds.

So $U$ is an open set in the box topology as well. Thus $U$ is the union of sets $V$ where each $V$ is the product of open sets $A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_n$ ($A_k \in T_k$). Thus we have $$f^{-1}(V) = f_1^{-1}(A_1) \cap \cdots \cap f_n^{-1}(A_n)$$

So $f^{-1}(V)$ is open. Because $f^{-1}(U)$ is the union of those sets for every $V$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Comment: The box topology is covered in the next chapter of the book I am reading, is there a way to prove this without the box topology?

Comment: I am going to think about it. However, the way the product topology is defined, if you want to prove something of the form "for every open set $U$,  $P(U)$ holds", you basically need to prove that a topology in which every open set has the property $P$ *exists*.

Comment: The other method of proof I tried was:  Let $V$ be an arbitrary open set in $\prod (X_i,T_i)$.  Then $V = \prod_{i} O_i$.  But I don't have a clear understanding of what $f^{-1}(\prod_{i} O_i)$ means.

Comment: I see that $f^{-1}(\prod_{i} O_i) = \{y : y \in Y \land <f_1(y), f_2(y), ..., f_n(y)> \in \prod_{i} O_i\}$, but from here I don't know how to relate this is what I mean.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the "finite" product topology is the same as the box topology: In the box topology, every open set is the union of sets of the form $\prod_i O_i$ (where every $O_i \subseteq X_i$ is open), and in the product topology, every open set is the union of sets $\prod_i O_i$, where every $O_i \subseteq X_i$ is open and _for all but finitely many $i$s, we have $O_i = X_i$_!

Comment: @OliverG: Ohh, in this case you are pretty much done since $< f_1(y), \dots, f_n(y) > \in \prod_i O_i$ just means $f_1(y) \in O_1$ and $f_2(y) \in O_2$ ... and $f_n(y) \in O_n$.

Comment: So since $f^{-1}(\prod_{i} O_i) = \{y : y \in Y \land f_i(y) \in O_i \}$
This is $\{y : y \in Y \land y \in f^{-1}_{i}(O_i)\}$ and each $f^{-1}_{i}(O_i)$ is open because each $f_i$ is continuous.  So it's the set of all elements in an open set, which is an open set?

Comment: Exactly. As one little nitpick, I'd write it as $f^{-1}(\prod_i O_i) = \{y : y \in Y \land \bigwedge_i f_i(y) \in O_i\} = \bigcap_i f^{-1}(O_i)$ to emphasize that it is the __intersection__ of finitely many open sets (which is an open set).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add some information about the categorical point of view of the product topology. What you are asked to prove is essentially the universal property of the product topology. If $X=\prod_i X_i$ and $p_i\colon X\to X_i$ the $i$-th projection, then for every topological space $Y$ and continuous functions $f_i\colon Y\to X_i$ there exists a unique continuous function $f\colon Y\to X$ such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]